# Reference for the symmetric group $S_n$ and all its subgroups for each $n$?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Is there any reference that contains a list of all the subgroups contained in $S_n$ for at least up to $n = 10$? If they contained the cycle-graphs and other group properties as well even better.

Something akin to OEIS but for groups would be great.

Comment: here's a resource for, e.g., $n=6$: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_group:S6 If this is what you are looking for, you can check whether higher $n$ cases are dealt with as well.

Answer (score 4):

I would strongly recommend using GAP or Magma to do this. It will give you the answer is a useful form! For example, $S_{10}$ has a total of 29594446 subgroups split up into 1593 conjugacy classes. In GAP:

```
gap> C := ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(SymmetricGroup(10));;
gap> Length(C);
1593
gap> Sum(List(C,x->Size(x)));
29594446
```

Or Magma:

```
> C:=Subgroups(Sym(10));
> #C;
1593
> &+[g`length:g in C];
29594446
```

This takes just a few seconds in both cases.

Comment: Is there a way to create a Hasse Diagram of the subgroups in GAP? Or graph the subgroup lattice?

Comment: Yes, you can use the GAP function $\mathsf{LatticeSubgroups}$ - I just tried it, and it took less than 30 seconds for $S_{10}$. You will have to look at [manual](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap39.html#X7FA267497CFC0550) for details on the functionality that this provides.